# SSH login from external authentication

Tags: ssh, git, authentication, pam

Here is what I try to accomplish:
I have a server with a git repository.
I use ISPConfig as control panel for our websites and I want to integrate the ISPConfig API for email authentication as second authentication.

Here is the authentication flow:

1. The user connects with ssh-rsa key (without password)
2. The ssh has to run a script which prompts the user for second authentication with email and password. These credentials are verified with the API and if correct the user is logged in through SSH, otherwise the user is disconnected.

**EDIT**:
I've installed the **libpam_script** (`apt-get install libpam_script`) and tried to configure it, but with no luck.
I've tried several things by adding this line `auth    required        pam_script.so` to:
`/etc/pam.d/sshd`
`/etc/pam.d/login`
`/etc/pam.d/common-auth`

None of them executed the script `/etc/security/onauth` nor `/usr/share/libpam-script/pam_script_auth`
In both scripts I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Logging" > /home/server/pam.log
```

The code is just for testing to see if it's even executed.

Comment: The SSH login will be with ssh-rsa key and I'm trying to integrate a second authentication through a script which is ran after the user logs with SSH.

Comment: You might want to put that into the question - as it is now I would really rend to suggest closing as *"unclear what you're asking"*.

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: I've tried so many things with pam_script. Nothing really worked.

Comment: So `pam_script` doesn't work even when logging in on console (through `login`)?

Comment: Well I don't see the output of the script. PS: I'm logging with ssh-rsa key, if it matters

Comment: It might - when logging in with a key, ssh uses PAM only for account setting (limits etc.), not for authentication as such. If you can, check whether `login` triggers the pam script.

Comment: ``login`` does not trigger the script. In ``/var/log/auth.log`` I see the following output: ``Jan 14 16:09:04 dokov sshd[6211]: Accepted publickey for server from **.**.**.** port 47808 ssh2
Jan 14 16:09:04 dokov sshd[6211]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user server by (uid=0)``

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12486/discussion-between-ivan-dokov-and-peterph)

Comment: But actually I thin pam_script cannot **prompt** the user for second authentication. It cannot interact with the user.